# Android: webview loading problem

Tags: android, webview

I am loading web page content using web view, But some time i am facing "ERROR/Web Console(889): TypeError: Result of expression 'this.mb' [null] is not an object." this error.
How to resolve this problem. Please help anyone.

Thanks,
Baskar

Answer (score 0):

You should add the given blow code i think in your code plugin or java script are not enabled.

```
WebView webView=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

I hope this is help.

Comment: This problem facing only some urls. why?